# How to load several environment variables without cluttering the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I am working on a simple Docker image that has a large number of environment variables. Are you able to import an environment variable file like with docker-compose? I cannot find anything about this in the docker file documentation.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV ENV1 9.3
ENV ENV2 9.3.4
...

ADD . /

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./manager.py" ]
```

I guess a good way to rephrase the question would be: how do you efficiently load multiple environment variables in a Dockerfile? If you are not able to load a file, you would not be able to commit a docker file to GitHub.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, the `--build-arg` flag to `docker build` may be useful.

Comment: Do you need the environment variables for building the image, or do you need them when you run the image?

Comment: I need them when I run the image.

Comment: You can do it during `docker run`, not `docker build`. You can use `docker run --env-file [path-toenv-file]` to provide the environment variables to the container from a `.env` file.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple of ways you can do this.

### Docker Compose

In Docker Compose, you can supply environment variables in the file itself, or point to an external env file:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:

  service-name:
    image: service-app
    environment:
    - GREETING=hello
    env_file:
    - .env
```

Incidentally, one nice feature that is somewhat related is that you can use multiple Compose files, with each subsequent one adding to the other. So if the above were to define a base, you can then do this (e.g. per run-time environment):

```
# docker-compose-dev.yml
version: '2'
services:

  service-name:
    environment:
    - GREETING=goodbye
```

You can then run it thus:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-dev.yml up
```

### Docker only

To do this in Docker only, use your entrypoint or command to run an intermediate script, thus:

```
#Dockerfile

....

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "bin/start.sh"]
```

And then in your start script:

```
#!/bin/sh

source .env

python /manager.py
```

I've [used this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186458/472495) as a helpful reference for myself in the past.

### Update on PID 1

To amplify my remark in the comments, if you make your entry point a shell or Python script, it is likely that [Unix signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) (stop, kill, etc) will not be passed onto your process. This is because that script will become [process ID 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), which makes it the parent process of all other processes in the container - in Linux/Unix there is an expectation that this PID will forward signals to its children, but unless you explicitly implement that, it won't happen.

To rectify this, you can install an init system. I use [dumb-init from Yelp](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init). This repo also features plenty of detail if you want to understand it a bit better, or simple install instructions if you just want to "install and forget".

Comment: But the question is if this is possible without docker-compose? It seems like a bit of an overkill if all that I want is this .env file...

Comment: @hY8vVpf3tyR57Xib: ah, I see what you mean. I wonder, perhaps `RUN source .env`? Or do `CMD ["sh", "start.sh"]` which does that source command prior to starting your Python program.

Comment: @halfer Actually, I would be interested in your advice on "how to handle unix signals correctly". I do not know what you mean by dumb init system.

Comment: @RichardKiefer: answer edited, let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 17):

I really like @halfers approach, but this could also work. `docker run` takes an optional parameter called `--env-file` which is super helpful.

So your docker file could look like this.

```
COPY .env .env
```

and then in a build script use:

```sh
docker build -t my_docker_image . && docker run --env-file .env my_docker_image
```

Comment: VOLUME ["/conf.d", "/mnt/logs"] - what does it mean?

Comment: Ahh good catch! This would be mounting volumes to your docker container. These two volumes would be specifically for logging and monitoring tools like DataDog.

Comment: Do you want to remove FROM and VOLUME strings to make the answer more readable?

Comment: Why do i need `COPY .env .env` ? The referenced --env-file for docker run could have any name, right? E.g. `docker run --env-file .local.env my_docker_image`. Am I missing some point here?

Answer (score 14):

There are various options:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e-env-env-file

```
docker run -e MYVAR1 --env MYVAR2=foo --env-file ./env.list ubuntu bash
```

(You can also just reference previously `exported` variables, see `USER` below.)

The one answering your question about an .env file is:

```
cat env.list
# This is a comment
VAR1=value1
VAR2=value2
USER

docker run --env-file env.list ubuntu env | grep VAR
VAR1=value1
VAR2=value2

docker run --env-file env.list ubuntu env | grep USER
USER=denis
```

You can also load the environment variables from a file. This file should use the syntax `variable=value` (which sets the variable to the given value) or `variable` (which takes the **value from the local environment**), and # for comments.

Regarding the difference between variables needed at (image) build time or (container) runtime and how to combine `ENV` and `ARG` for dynamic build arguments you might try this:
[ARG or ENV, which one to use in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916386/arg-or-env-which-one-to-use-in-this-case)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the `$BASH_ENV` environment variable and override the `SHELL` in your `Dockerfile`. This will probably not work for all situations because it doesn't set the environment variables globally but it might work for you.

`env.sh`

```
export FOO=BAR
```

`script.sh`

```
echo "FOO = ${FOO}" > /test
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.6

COPY env.sh /env.sh

ENV BASH_ENV=/env.sh

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

COPY script.sh /script.sh

RUN /script.sh
```

And this will give the following output:

```
docker build -t example .

docker run example cat /test
FOO = BAR
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need environment variables runtime, it's easiest to create a launcher script that sets up the environment with multiple `export` statements and then launches your process.

If you need them build time, have a look at the `ARG` and `ENV` statements. You'll need one per variable.

Answer (score 0):

Without `docker-compose.yml` (as most VPS CPanels (open-source PaaS like Dokku, Caprover, Easypanel) don't support `docker-compose.yml`) so I had to find an alternate solution using `--env-file` option in a `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: build-staging
build-staging: ## Build the staging docker image.
    docker build -f docker/staging/Dockerfile -t easypanel-nextjs:0.0.1 .

.PHONY: start-staging
start-staging: ## Start the staging docker container.
    docker run --detach --env-file .env.staging --publish 3000:3000 --restart unless-stopped easypanel-nextjs:0.0.1

.PHONY: stop-staging
stop-staging: ## Stop the staging docker container.
    docker stop $$(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=easypanel-nextjs:0.0.1)
```

Now, I just do this in the terminal:

```bash
$ make build-staging
$ make start-staging
$ make stop-staging
```

Obviously, the syntax becomes much cleaner with `docker compose` but most VPS CPanels don't support it so this is as good as it gets.

My repo that uses this method -> https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite