# Dockerfile: Is there any way to read variables from .env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I want to read the `PORT` variable inside Dockerfile which is defined in `.env` file. 
Is there any way to do this?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PORT=3000

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: you can include the env file within the docker file... or you can pass in the environment variables when you use docker-run

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917831/can-you-use-a-env-file-for-a-stand-alone-dockerfile/46919859

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATED**

After discussion in a chat was realised that there's no problem with the nodejs app container, and the issue comes from a wrongly configured nginx proxy.

Proof for the working nodejs app is the next docker-compose file.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
    api:
        build: .
    curl:
        image: curlimages/curl:7.70.0
        depends_on:
          - api
        entrypoint: ""
        command: curl -si --retry 5 --retry-delay 5 --retry-max-time 40 http://api:6000
        restart: on-failure
```

**ORIGINAL**

If you want to change the port while a build process (it will be static later when you run a container) then use build-args

```sh
docker build --build-arg APP_PORT=3000
```

```
FROM node:11-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG APP_PORT=80
EXPOSE ${APP_PORT}

COPY . .
RUN APP_PORT=${APP_PORT} npm install

CMD APP_PORT=${APP_PORT} npm run start
```

if you want to be able to change the port when you're starting a container - then build-args don't fit and you need to stay with `env` variables. Notice that after build `EXPOSE` can't be changed.

Anyway if you have different ports in `EXPOSE` and your app listens to - it doesn't break anything, the app's port will be available on the port you want, despite it wasn't specified in `EXPOSE`.

You can even skip `EXPOSE` in your file, because it's rather more a metadata information of your image than an instruction for a system to open the port: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

> Regardless of the EXPOSE settings, you can override them at runtime by using the -p flag.

if your image is static after the build (you don't plan to change .env) you can do next, then `npm install` and `npm run start` has the same env. And you're still allowed to change port later, but it won't affect npm install.

```
FROM node:11-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .
RUN export $(cat .env) && npm install 

CMD export $(cat .env) && npm run start
```

if you have to keep `CMD` as an array - then we need to create a bootstrap script

```
FROM node:11-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .
RUN export $(cat .env) && npm install

RUN echo '#!/usr/bin/env sh' > start.sh && echo 'export $(cat .env) && npm run start ${@}' >> start.sh
CMD ["sh", "./start.sh"]
```

Comment: in my express app I am reading the PORT value from .env file

I am running the program like this `dotenv -e .env yarn start`

so, port is getting from env file.

But, is it possible to get the same PORT value in dockerFile ?

otherwise, if APP_PORT is different than  .env files port, the app will not run properly.

Comment: Not sure if it the best solution, at least it works :) `export $(cat .env)` is the trick, but it should be executed before every command, because after `RUN` they are gone.

Comment: in which file, I should add `export $(cat .env)`?

Comment: Check my answer - the latest option for `Dockerfile`, that's what should solve the issue. `CMD export $(cat .env) && npm run start`

Comment: Unfortunately, It is not working, here is my dockerFIle and docker-compose file in case you need

https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/b13da5ee9f0392277d38a5786de82f27

I am getting 'server is listening on port 6000' in console. but actually it is not listening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213473/discussion-between-satantime-and-ashik).

Comment: I've updated my answer that the problem is within nginx config and not with the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)  in your Dockerfile which is meant for this purpose.

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant to the question asked.