# Multiple Docker build args from docker-compose .env file

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am experiencing an odd issue with docker-compose's `.env` file. I am able to use the first variable key=pair in my .env file, but only the first variable. This is my folder structure

```
|- root
|  |- .env
|  |- docker-compose.yaml
|  |- service-1
|     |- Dockerfile
```

.env:

```
GIT_TOKEN=c3e13c4e33935
DB_PWD=mypassword
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
web-server:
      container_name: service-1
      image: sdc/service-1:0.1
      build:
        context: ./service-1
        args:
          - GIT_TOKEN=$GIT_TOKEN
          - DB_PWD=$DB_PWD
```

service-1/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:boron
ARG GIT_TOKEN
ARG DB_PWD
RUN git clone https://${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/chrxn/sdc.git
RUN echo {"database_password:" $DB_PWD } > crews.txt
```

The problem is that the GIT_TOKEN variable is working perfectly, but the DB_PWD variable is not. Even if put the GIT_TOKEN variable in the echo line, the token is saved to a file (so I know it isn't an echo/bash interpolation issue) Any help is greatly appreciated. I have read everything I can find related to Docker's environment variables.

NOTE: I've modified a few things. My database password is not mypassword and that isn't a real git repo

References:

- [.env file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/)
- [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args)
- [Similar example but setting container environment variables](https://staxmanade.com/2016/05/how-to-get-environment-variables-passed-through-docker-compose-to-the-containers/)
- [False issue raised because .env and env_file is so confusing](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4223)
- [combine ARG and ENV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916386/arg-or-env-which-one-to-use-in-this-case#answer-41919137)

I really would like to stick to Docker build arguments instead of environmental variables so that the values are not stored in the container's environment variables.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Facepalm ‍♀️ - This is working perfectly. I was putting the `- DB_PWD=$DB_PWD` argument under the wrong service in my `docker-compose.yaml` file. I will leave this here as a reference on how to use the `.env` file with docker build arguments -- and as a reminder to my self that I'm an idiot. I'm embarrassed --100 SOF reputation

Comment: How do we use args from a file?

Comment: Thanks I also had a typo under `args`. But this post made me sure I am on the right track and corrected my config. Especially doing `- VAR=$VAR` instead of `- VAR=${VAR}`. Still the real problem was that I typoed like `- REPOSITORY_URL=$REPOSITYORY_URL`.   Posting what you did wrong also helps others!

Comment: Ultimately this ends up being really simple, but there are so many damn ways to do it wrong.  Arghh

Comment: @RajSrujanJalem: You have the variables stored in an `.env` file and docker makes them available. You can just access them how OP did: `GIT_TOKEN=$GIT_TOKEN`

Answer (score -1):

```
`version: '3'
web-server:
      container_name: service-1
      image: sdc/service-1:0.1
      build:
        context: ./service-1
        args:
          - GIT_TOKEN=${GIT_TOKEN}
          - DB_PWD=$DB_PWD
```