# How can I load multiple environment variables into the building image in docker build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have these 3 files.

```
▶ ls
.env  docker-compose.yml  Dockerfile
```

These are the contents.

```
▶ cat .env
ABC=123

▶ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"
services:

  test:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .

▶ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine:latest

RUN printenv
```

When I try to build an image with `.env` through docker-compose, `printenv` in the building image doesn't print `ABC`

```
▶ docker-compose build --no-cache test
Building test
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> d4ff818577bc
Step 2/2 : RUN printenv
 ---> Running in a2ddef17b235
HOSTNAME=a2ddef17b235
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
Removing intermediate container a2ddef17b235
 ---> 05b8242e2d25
Successfully built 05b8242e2d25
Successfully tagged doenv-in-compose_test:latest
```

I know I can use `ARG` and `--build-arg` to embed env vars in the building image.

*notice the ABC=777

```
▶ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine:latest

ARG ABC

RUN printenv

▶ docker-compose build --no-cache --build-arg ABC=777 test
Building test
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> d4ff818577bc
Step 2/3 : ARG ABC
 ---> Running in e6aed0723b7b
Removing intermediate container e6aed0723b7b
 ---> 92e4a7350e24
Step 3/3 : RUN printenv
 ---> Running in b20a3a4418ca
HOSTNAME=b20a3a4418ca
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ABC=777
PWD=/
Removing intermediate container b20a3a4418ca
 ---> 4386eb200523
Successfully built 4386eb200523
Successfully tagged doenv-in-compose_test:latest
```

However, in my real case, I have some 10 different variables in the dotenv file, it's not really suitable to list them all in Dockerfile and command line.

Is there a way to load .env file into the image when to build?

Comment: The `build:` phase happens before most other things in the `docker-compose.yml` are considered, including `env_file:`.  What sort of things do you have in the `.env` file?  Do you have that many configuration options describing how to build the image?  Or do you only need these values when you're eventually running the container?

Comment: (See also [Use docker-compose env variable in Dockerbuild file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261811/use-docker-compose-env-variable-in-dockerbuild-file) or [Multiple Docker build args from docker-compose .env file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451060/multiple-docker-build-args-from-docker-compose-env-file); the latter implicitly notes that [Compose will read the `.env` file into its own environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) but they still need to be in `args:`.)

Comment: (And also remember that anything that's in an `ARG` can be trivially retrieved later by anyone who has the image.  The setup in the "Multiple Docker build args" question, for example, makes Git credentials visible in `docker history`, which is probably bad.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I build a nextjs app in the image.   To build a nextjs app, you need a lot of different environment variables.   Since nextjs apps need the vars at its build time, I need them when I build the docker image...   I am currently using docker-compose to first build this nextjs app, then create an image by picking specific files that the build created.