# Send variables into docker container to use in a script

Tags: shell, variables, docker, scripting, docker-compose

I am running a script in the CI/CD of the pipeline. The goal is to get a string to work with.
When I get that result, I save it into a variable and save result in the yaml file of the dockerfile.

I am wanting to pass that variable from the CI environment, into the docker-compose container. So, I am trying to export this like another things are exported, however it doesn't work:

```
ci/pdf/jenkins-changes.sh
LOG="$(cat ".log")"
export LOG
```

I have added a variables.env file that looks like this:

```
LOG=LOG
```

And then modified the docker-compose.yaml to read the var :

`pdf:
    image: thisimage/this
    build:
    context: ../
    dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.name
    args:
        git_branch: ${GIT_BRANCH}
    env_file:
    - variables.env
    environment:
    - LOG=${LOG}
    volumes:
    - do-build:/src/do-build`

And in the script that finally runs the docker-container, I have also 
Declared it:
    FROM ubuntu:16.04 as pdf-builder

```
ARG log
ENV log=${log}
RUN LOG=${log}
RUN export $LOG
```

And right after, I run the script.sh that requires the variable, however, it returns Unbound variable and breaks.

```
LOG=${log}
echo ${LOG}
```

Comment: you donot need to export it once you put in env and here you doing what LOG=${LOG}? you passing env file and aslo env variable

Comment: Not even if I want to access it from a shell script, because right after, I do a Run make script.sh , and the script says that can't find it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651369/docker-one-or-more-build-args-where-not-consumed/49655913#49655913 check my answer regarding env and args

Comment: Yeah I just added it as an edit. The Script does some logic with the var but basically that's when it goes wrong

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found that answer before

Comment: so you can upvote ;)

Comment: I thought I had :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was:

```
ci/pdf/jenkins-changes.sh 
LOG="$(cat ".log")"
export LOG
```

Then pass it as an argument, instead of a variable:

```
pdf:
    image: thisimage/this
    build:
    context: ../
    dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.name
    args:
        git_branch: ${GIT_BRANCH}
    env_file:
    - variables.env
    environment:
    - LOG=${LOG}
    volumes:
    - do-build:/src/do-build
```

And then, in the dockerfile call it and define it.

```
ARG log
```

This should leave it global for any script to use it.