# Nested variables in a Makefile to provide conditional support to docker

Tags: docker, makefile

I have variables set in an env file called by my Makefile. I would like to choose a set variable based on an environment condition. Is there a way to nest two variables to make a new variable?

Example env file

```
FILE_VERSION_11=11.0.4
```

Execution

```
VER=11 make build
```

Example Makefile (Not working obviously)

```
.PHONY: all
.PHONY: build
.PHONY: clean
.PHONY: help
.PHONY: test

include env

build: ## Build
build:
  docker image build --pull -t container:file-version-$(VER) \
  --build-arg FILE_VERSION=$(FILE_VERSION_$VER)
```

Hoping to have the `$(FILE_VERSION)` variable now be rewritten as `$(FILE_VERSION_11)` so that 11.0.4 can be passed to the docker build via the `FILE_VERSION_11` env variable.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Computed-Names.html

Comment: I saw that and that MIGHT be a solution. I'm trying to figure out how to essentially make `FILE_VERSION_$VER` into a variable that will call `$FILE_VERSION_11` or `$FILE_VERSION_8` from the env file. Just having trouble wrapping my head around the logic.

Comment: I think the correct syntax is FILE_VERSION=$(FILE_VERSION_$(VER))

Comment: That makes `FILE_VERSION=_11` because I screwed up, so I changed it to `FILE_VERSION=FILE_VERSION_$(VAR)` but that still doesn't convert the variable to `$FILE_VERSION_11` and doesn't set the contents of `$FILE_VERSION_11` to `$FILE_VERSION`.

Error:
`[Warning] One or more build-args [FILE_VERSION] were not consumed`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
--build-arg FILE_VERSION=$(FILE_VERSION_$(VER))
```

And in the Dockerfile you need to specify which args could be [passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651369/docker-one-or-more-build-args-where-not-consumed) via `--build-arg` option:

```
FROM <image>

ARG FILE_VERSION

RUN echo $FILE_VERSION
```

Comment: As I stated in the comments above this didn't work either. Working through some options with someone at work. I will update this thread if a solution becomes available.