# Docker: One or more build-args [SSH_PRIVATE_KEY] were not consumed (but it should have)

Tags: docker, warnings, docker-build

I have this Dockerfile snippet:

```
FROM alpine/git:v2.26.2 as intermediate

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/ && chmod 755 /root/.ssh
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 && chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

It is run using this command:

`docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_runbot)" --tag org/name .`

I also checked this question [Docker, one or more build-args where not consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651369/docker-one-or-more-build-args-where-not-consumed)

So it looks I'm doing same thing as suggested. But I'm still getting this warning:

```
[Warning] One or more build-args [SSH_PRIVATE_KEY] were not consumed
```

`Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d`

P.S. I know that such warning is usually harmless, but I want to understand what am I doing wrong and why it is giving that warning when I think it should not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I was just on different working directory than I thought I was. So I was actually building different image, which is why I was getting that warning.