# Running the program in Docker with command line arguments

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, command-line-arguments

I need to write a program that accepts and outputs a command line argument. It is necessary to assemble it and run it in a container. Here's what I have:

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) > 2 {
        fmt.Println("arg: ", os.Args[1])
    } else {
        fmt.Println("no args")
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest

COPY . /tmp

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN go build -o app main.go

CMD [ "./app" ]
```

build:

```
sudo docker build -t test .
```

run:

```
sudo docker run test arg1
```

When I start, I get an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "arg1": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0002] error waiting for container:
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Use entrypoint to define the program. Command/cmd is passes as args to that, and command line args on the docker cli overwrite the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to pass the arguments given at container startup to the entrypoint of your software.

Dockerfile:

```
# ...
ENTRYPOINT [ "./app", $my_args ]
```

Commands:

```
sudo docker build -t test . 
sudo docker run -e my_args="arg1" test
```

You can also use a combination of ARG and ENV to create a default value that can be edited. Response from [Alexander Mills](https://Alexander%20Mills) on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50935383/12150524).

Edit: I didn't deduct from your question whether this program will be run as part of a larger process, but depending on whether you need to redirect STDOUT of the program called in the container (chain to other programs) use or omit the `-t` flag of the `docker run` command.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. You can invoke your container like this: `sudo docker run test ./app arg1 arg2 arg3`
2. change the last line of your Dockerfile to say this: `ENTRYPOINT [ "./app" ]`

There are subtle differences between ENTRYPOINT and CMD: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options