# define a locale environment variable in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is there any way to create local variables in `Dockerfile` that only available during the build process? What I can see is if I define a variable with the `ENV` keyword, then it will be available later in the image as an exported environment variable. But I would like to have a "technical" variable with build scope only.

I would like to avoid repetition in my Doclerfile so I would like to have a variable available only from the Dockerfile:

```
ENV MY_JAR=myJar.jar
COPY bin/$MY_JAR $ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/lib/
COPY bin/$MY_JAR $ORACLE_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/mbeantypes/
```

But the `MY_JAR` variable appears in the container. I do not need it there. It just confuses users. Can I do this somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ARG` instead of `ENV`

```
ARG MY_JAR=myJar.jar  # ARG is only available during the build of a Docker image
COPY bin/$MY_JAR $ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/lib/
COPY bin/$MY_JAR $ORACLE_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/mbeantypes/
```

see also [ARG or ENV, which one to use in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916386/arg-or-env-which-one-to-use-in-this-case)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--build-arg` parameter to pass environment variables that lives just during docker building process.

So your docker build command will look something like this

`docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234 -t sample:v1 .`

Where `HTTP_PROXY` is just available during the build process.