# Environment variables should not be checked in to repositories... what about dockerfille?

Tags: git, version-control, dockerfile, environment-variables, dotenv

I learned it's best to keep environment variable values outside of your source control. This is done by default obviously, but when using [dot-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), they [strongly advises against checking in the .env file](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-commit-my-env-file).

However, I need to have a docker file for my app so I can build and deploy it. I also decided to not use the [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) instruction inside my dockerfile because I check in that file into my repository.

But then how do I test my docker image on my machine if it doesn't have environment variables in it? I need to either:

- Set the environment variables on my machine to have production environment values

  - Which would be very annoying if I have to keep setting them and reverting them
- Store them in the docker file

  - Which would mean I would check it in my source control

My question is: Should I store environment variables in my dockerfile if it gets checked into my repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I store environment variables in my dockerfile if it gets checked into my repository?

You should not: Any value your Dockerfile need (value that you can get from an *external* referential, like a Git repository) can be passed as [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg).

You can then [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) your image using:

```
docker build --build-arg arg1=arg1Value .
```

In your Dockerfile, you would then have ([combining `ARG` and `ENV`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41919137/6309)):

```
ARG arg1
ENV myvar=${arg1}
...
```