# Can't access directory/volume created in Dockerfile; Django + Docker

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn

I'm new to Docker, and I'm trying to deploy a django site with Docker & Gunicorn. The Docker image builds just fine, but I keep getting this error when attempting to run it.

> touch: cannot touch '/srv/logs/gunicorn.log': No such file or directory
> touch: cannot touch '/srv/logs/access.log': No such file or directory
> Starting Gunicorn.
> tail: cannot open '/srv/logs/*.log' for reading: No such file or directory

If I had to bet, I would say it's an issue with me not understanding these Docker Volumes

Here are the relevant files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

MAINTAINER ozymandias
ENV DOCKYARD_SRC=agency
ENV DOCKHARD_SRVHOME=/srv
ENV DOCKYARD_SRVPROJ=/srv/agency

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

WORKDIR $DOCKYARD_SRC
RUN mkdir media static logs
VOLUME ["$DOCKYARD_SRVHOME/media/", "$DOCKYARD_SRVHOME/logs/"]
RUN ls

copy $DOCKYARD_SRC $DOCKYARD_SRVPROJ

RUN pip3 install -r $DOCKYARD_SRVPROJ/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR $DOCKYARD_SRVPROJ
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
ls
touch /srv/logs/gunicorn.log
touch /srv/logs/access.log
tail -n 0 -f /srv/logs/*.log &

echo Starting Gunicorn.
exec gunicorn front.wsgi:application \
    --name agency \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
    --workers 3 \
    --log-level=info \
    --log-file=/srv/logs/gunicorn.log \
    --access-logfile==/srv/logs/access.log \
    "$@"
```

Comment: try to use `ARG` instruction instead of `ENV`. You can see the difference between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916386/arg-or-env-which-one-to-use-in-this-case).

Comment: Reading through this it seems like `/srv/logs` _should_ exist when you launch the container, but its a roundabout path.  Can you start the setup sequence with `WORKDIR /srv`, create directories relative to the current directory, and remove all of the environment variable setup?  `VOLUME` largely has confusing side effects and I'd just delete the `VOLUME` line, which may or may not make a difference.

Comment: I'd also be interested to see what's in `docker run --rm --entrypoint ls your-image /`; I expect to see a `/agency` directory and wouldn't be surprised if there was a `/agency/$DOCKYARD_SRVHOME/logs` directory (with that literal string).  If you do I can explain why, but it's not clear in the Dockerfile reference.

Comment: I changed the Dockefile to avoid using the ENV variables, and removed the VOLUME[], and still get the same errors. The output of the command `docker run --rm --entrypoint ls ozy/django_one /` is : agency
bin
boot
dev
docker-entrypoint.sh
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var