# Docker build arg leaked into build environment

Tags: docker, yarnpkg

I was using Docker to build some frontend code:

```dockerfile
FROM docker-server/docker-images/ui/node:20.10.0-alpine AS webpack_build
ARG NODE_ENV
ARG SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN

WORKDIR /app
COPY package* yarn.lock webpack.config.prod.js .babelrc ./
COPY static ./static
RUN yarn install
RUN pwd && ls -la && ls -la /app/node_modules/.bin/
RUN NODE_ENV="${NODE_ENV}" SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN="${SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN}" node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.prod.js
```

When we pass `--build-arg NODE_ENV=production` to the `docker build` command, the `yarn install` skips some packages, but with other values, Yarn installs the other packages.
I have worked around it by using `RUN yarn install --production=false`.

I am suspecting the build arg has a play in this, but I couldn't find clear documentation about build arg becoming an environment variable for the `yarn install` shell command, is this by design?

Could someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: The [docs say](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#yarn-install---productiontruefalse-) "Yarn will not install any package listed in devDependencies if the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production"; does this help explain what you are seeing?

Comment: @Brits I understand the yarn part, but the SO question is about docker build arg leaking into the environment, is it by design?

Comment: See [Using ARG variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables) in the Dockerfile documentation.  They're visible through the Dockerfile but are not visible to the eventual `CMD`.

Comment: @DavidMaze that's not what I have experienced unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find it in the [Build arguments docs](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/build-args/), and [ARG or ENV, which one to use in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916386/arg-or-env-which-one-to-use-in-this-case) is informative, but doesn't really answer the question either.

The [`ARG` reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) provides a few more details, but doesn't completely explain if `ARG` creates environment variables:

> An `ARG` variable definition comes into effect from the line on which it is defined in the Dockerfile not from the argument's use on the command-line or elsewhere. For example, consider this Dockerfile:
>
> […]
>
> An `ARG` instruction goes out of scope at the end of the build stage where it was defined. To use an argument in multiple stages, each stage must include the `ARG` instruction.

Further down:

> You can use an `ARG` or an `ENV` instruction to specify variables that are available to the `RUN` instruction. Environment variables defined using the `ENV` instruction always override an `ARG` instruction of the same name. Consider this Dockerfile with an `ENV` and `ARG` instruction.
>
> […]
>
> Unlike an `ARG` instruction, `ENV` values are always persisted in the built image.

From a quick test, it seems that yes, the `ARG` instruction sets an environment variable – but only for the duration of the build. The variable is not visible when running the container (that's what [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) is for).

Here's how you can verify yourself:

```
$ cat >Dockerfile <<'EOF
FROM alpine
ARG test
RUN printenv
EOF
$ docker build --build-arg test=42 .
```

This will print the environment variables  while building the image and you will find "test=42" in the output.

Comment: yeah exactly, I also tried chatgpt(low confidence I know), and it said if I want to use as environment value for the build, I had to do `ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV`

Comment: @JamesLin ChatGPT is a text generator that will produce plausible-looking text. Anything it generates can be misleading or plain wrong. `ENV` exports the variable as an environment variable in the running container. `ARG` is only available during build time.

Comment: yeah I know, I ran out of places to look for an answer. And yes everywhere I find ARG is only available during build time, but it's a bit vague about being environment value in build time.